# Delegate doesn't notify the method

Tags: c#, delegates

Would you look at my code and tell me where I went wrong? in following code I am trying to send a notification to `myMethod()` method when Form1 gets maximized.

Thanks!

```
namespace WindowsDelegate1
{

    public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    class myForm : Form
    {
        public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;

        protected virtual void OnChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Changed != null)
                Changed(this,e);
        }

        public override System.Drawing.Size MaximumSize
        {
            //get
            //{
            //    return base.MaximumSize;
            //}
            set
            {
                base.MaximumSize = value;
                OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}


namespace WindowsDelegate1
{
    class EventListener
    {
        private myForm TheForm;

        public EventListener(myForm theform)
        {
            TheForm = theform;
            TheForm.Changed += new ChangedEventHandler(myMethod);
        }

        private void myMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hey, window should be maximized now!");
        }

        public void Detach()
        {
            TheForm.Changed -= new ChangedEventHandler(myMethod);
            TheForm = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the testing unit / or main()

```
namespace WindowsDelegate1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myForm f = new myForm();
            EventListener listener = new EventListener(f);
            f.ShowDialog();
            f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            listener.Detach();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think my mistake was because I used a property rather method of Form class.

Comment: Just a quick comment, please don't edit your question after you've got the answer -- leave the question as it was and just put the answer in its own section below, that way future readers don't get confused about what the original problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for sharing your ideas!

I fixed it by removing the property (not idea why I used that!!) and using method instead by:

```
protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnActivated(e);
    OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

I have updated my source code above too

Answer (score 1):

What's probably happening is the event is either fired after your `.Detach()` call, or is never fired at all. I would start by removing the `listener.Detach()` call. Generally, you attach to events when the form is created or when it loads and detach when it is unloading.

Other than that, your `Detach` method is problematic because it tries to remove a different `ChangedEventHandler` instance than the one added. If you're wrapping your methods in `ChangedEventHandler` you need to store the instance you added.

Comment: Good advise I will consider it. Thanks.